# please explain this for-loop to me

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Can you please explain me this `for-loop`?

```
beanNote bnote = new beanNote();
String somme=0;
for (Note note : bnote.getNotes()) {
     somme = somme + note.getNoteMat();
}
```

I only known the classic `for-loop` like :

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
   // do job .....
}
```

Comment: What is a boocle or boucl?

Comment: search for _enhanced for loop_ or _for each loop_.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc there are people that doesn't know about the name of the enhanced loop or about a `for-each`, it's not a crime.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc yes, we're here to help people, but I don't think *read it out loud* would be the first step to teach programming concepts.

Answer (score 4):

It is equivalent to :

> for (Note note = bnote.getFirstNote(); bnote.stillNotes() ; note =
>   bnote.getTheFolowingNote() ) {
>
> ```
> somme = somme + note.getNoteMat();
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Wrong: This "foreach loop" only works with `Iterable`s, but I understand what you're implying.

Comment: it is wrong of course as a CODE but as EXPLANATION it does answer the newbie question.

Comment: Then rather, as a suggested, put it as blockquote than as code block.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (Note note : bnote.getNotes()) {
     somme = somme + note.getNoteMat();
}
```

Its e`nhanced for-loop`, it is some times even called as `for-each loop` introduced in java version 5, which makes iterating over collections and arrays flexible.

[**For-Each Loop**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is a for-each construct: bnote.getNotes() returns an array or an Iterable object and the body of the loop is executed for each of the objects in that collection.